# How to install 3 different versions fo mysql in a single instance(Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql

I need to install 3 different versions of mysql-server in a single instance(Ubuntu). 
1. MySQL server 5.6.24
2. MySQL server 5.6.32
3. MySQL server 5.7 latest release

Can anyone tell me the process to install all the above versions.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see how to do so using the traditional `apt` setup so I found this solution which uses `docker` to install as many versions of `mysql` on your ubuntu instance:

Steps:

1. Install default mysql using apt:

   ```
   sudo apt install sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
   ```
2. The install docker:

   ```
   curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
   ```
3. Install the version of `mysql` you want and assign it to a different port:

   ```
   sudo docker run --name mysql-56-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword -d mysql:5.6
   ```

   - `127.0.0.1:3310:3306` forwards port `3306` on docker to port `3310` on host

Now you have both mysql 5.7, and 5.6 connection can be made like thus:

1. To docker image:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3310
   ```
2. To host mysql:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

Please note I used fictitious mysql instances your will vary.

Further information:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: thanks, it's helped me

Comment: having installed in a docker container it's like you have it on another server.